# std::weak_ptr assignment with std::make_shared

Tags: c++11, weak-ptr, make-shared

I stumbled upon this behaviour when using `std::weak_ptr` and `std::make_shared` and I found it a little weird. I am using C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::weak_ptr<int> weak;

  std::shared_ptr<int> shared {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
  weak = shared;
  std::cout << "Meaning of life: " << *weak.lock() << std::endl;

  weak = std::make_shared<int>(23);
  std::cout << "Meaning of life: " << *weak.lock() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The first `std::cout` prints fine, the second gives me a segfault. I tried looking at the pages of `std::weak_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) but I still don't understand why this happens. Having to create a temporary object feels cumbersome to me, is this something that has been addressed in C++14 or is there something I am failing to see?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `weak_ptr` can only be dereferenced after locking if a `shared_ptr` object still exists that's pointing to the same underlying object.

In your first part

```
std::shared_ptr<int> shared {std::make_shared<int>(42)};
weak = shared;
std::cout << "Meaning of life: " << *weak.lock() << std::endl;
```

this is indeed the case. In the second part

```
weak = std::make_shared<int>(23);
std::cout << "Meaning of life: " << *weak.lock() << std::endl;
```

it is not the case, as the `shared_ptr` was a temporary object.

What you've encountered here is exactly what `weak_ptr` was built for - that it be valid only as long as some other `shared_ptr` points to the same underlying object. That is [its purpose](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr):

> std::weak_ptr is a smart pointer that holds a non-owning ("weak") reference to an object that is managed by std::shared_ptr... If the original std::shared_ptr is destroyed at this time, the object's lifetime is extended until the temporary std::shared_ptr is destroyed as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact that you create a temporary shared pointer and assign it to a weak pointer right away in this line:

```
weak = std::make_shared<int>(23);
```

After the assignment operator ends, the temporary shared pointer is destructed, the reference count reaches 0 (since weak pointers do not increase the reference counter) and hence, the resource on the heap is deleted.